# div styles disappear while dragging elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, react-sortable-hoc

Trying to create a draggable div, When click and drag the `dropdown` div css it should be hidden. When dragging finished `div` css should be shown again.Is there any way I can achieve this using CSS?

For drag and drop, I am using this library "react-sortable-hoc"

https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc

On drag click this className `st-drag-icon` should be called.

code snippet: (some error on code compile)

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-cerf-cwfgl

Issue Video:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12nUf_-PXH2BPWnHcsXlnOoBbtOFzwpee/view?usp=sharing

I would also be very appreciative to know why this happens and any other tips one may have.

Hope this help you !

Comment: Can you guys help me [@ariel-frischer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715153/ariel-frischer) [@brian-adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10149510/brian-adams) [@dekel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5037551/dekel) [@sebastian-b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486382/sebastian-b) [@dev-sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12619405/dev-sebastian) [@hmr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1641941/hmr) [@andrei-rosu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3238392/andrei-rosu) [@amr-labib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6394644/amr-labib)

Comment: Please send me working sample of codesandbox. I can give a try to solve this issue